# How to format pagination in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I want to format pagination in laravel like this:

```
api/posts?from=1&to=10
```

I tried:

```
$posts = new LengthAwarePaginator(Post::all(), 100, 10);
return $posts->toArray();
```

Which didn’t work at all :( Please help

Comment: Do you want to change the names of query parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the pagination object [as shown in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#converting-results-to-json).

Answer (score 0):

your url should be api/posts?limit=10

and you can use in your controller as

```
Post::paginate(request('limit'));
```

it generates

```
{
"total": 50,
"per_page": 15,
"current_page": 1,
"last_page": 4,
"first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
"last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
"next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
"prev_page_url": null,
"path": "http://laravel.app",
"from": 1,
"to": 15,
"data":[
    {
        // Result Object
    },
    {
        // Result Object
    }
]
}
```

to get the next page in pagination your url should be as 
api/posts?page={page number}&limit=10

limit can be changed according to requirement